# Why R, T matrix get wrong when I use unique intrinsic matrix for each cameras?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I faced a problem when I tried to find R,T matrix using stereoCalibrate() function in Opencv.

I'm using 8 Logitech C922 webcams and I'm trying to find relative pose between them.

When I find intrinsic matrix for each of cameras and use them for stereo calibration, it yields wrong R and T (especially when distance between cameras gets further)

BUT, when I use one of the intrinsic matrix for all of the cameras(use same intrinsic matrix for all of cameras), stereo calibration yields much more accurate R and T.

anyone knows why this happens?

I use chessboard for calibration and use stereoCalibrate() function like bellow.

```
float re_error = stereoCalibrate(ChessCornerPoints, imageCorner0, imageCorner1, camMatrix0, distCoeffs0, camMatrix1, distCoeffs1, camera_sz, R, T, E, F)
```

should I use additional flags..?

Comment: Do you calibrate each camera separately? If so, you can use FIX_INTRINSIC flag to stereoCalibrate to fix intrinsic matrices for all of the cameras.

Comment: @PiotrSiekański Yes, I did it separately. As I know, if I don't write any flag, it uses CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC for default.

Comment: OK, can you post the intrinsic matrices, distortion coeffs and relative camera poses?